# How do i convert Gray to RGB in nrrd file

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

i trying convert grayscale 3D image to RGB 3D image.

Now i can get each slice's array. this array value's grayscale pixel value.

but i don't know how to covert RGB value.

i tried convert color using opencv function.

```
import numpy as np
import nrrd
import cv2

data = nrrd.read('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\sample data\\sample_nrrd.nrrd')
print(data[0][442][376])
cv2.cvtColor(data,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

but it's not working...

i first time using nrrd file.

how to convert gray to rgb.

And this array is example of my data.

Thanks.

[-1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000
 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000    80   236  1830  1901  1852  1742  1430
  1147  1088  1285  1240   989   969   787   791  1073  1098  1380  1320
  1125  1075  1209  1433  1505  1349  1114  1261  1463  1454  1696  1435
  1301  1448  1384  1146  1220  1054   829  1189  1245  1319  1293   986
   695   672   594   709   583   503   601   562   440   418   764   967
  1275   911   842   761   652   479   691   715   505   442   768   650
   705   938  1079  1076   969   936   907   902   755   588   614   770
   738   646   971   802   625   890  1020   929   941   824   800   803
   920   843   793   834   937   877   737   494   621   605   763   825
   642   548   527   427   552   529   572   345   442   455   603   614
   712   521   603   687   770   665   744   604   642   791   971   980
  1059  1020   842   781   793   845   860   982   916  1077   907   491
   806   533   327   709   817   913   977   735   958   624   547   651
   952  1171  1184  1033  1262  2015  2193  2444  2830  2678  2650  2473
  2528  2766  2915  2991  2654  2403  2700  2646  2302  2276  2706  3003
  2639  2499  2414  1948  1456  1908  1409   852   500   946   747   715
   864   899   960   977   807   954  1348  1053  1242  1346  1732  1634
  1600  1690  1730  1797  1833  1963  1795  1775  2016  2182  2260  2132
  1912  1651  1380  1576  1768  2275  1934  1790  1740  1908  2061  2068
  1879  1714  1801  1678  1588  1669  1717  1596  1573  2080  1869  1922
  2080  1701  2003  1617  1917  1810  1437  1292  1110   813  1079  1166
  1037  1111  1518  1417  1037   603   120   137    15   -30  -197  -409
  -133   -72    80     7    10    -7   -28    29  -219   -12     3    18
   144   120   -89    -4   101   143    66  -162    96   218   153   120
    36   188   275    58   -64    28     9   -77    89   202   206   243
   349   234    54   163   262   313   282   131   175   234   102   263
   109    93    57   143   282   235   175   189   217   200   297   345
   314   150   -24   105   111   202   -58    20   -67  -175   -39   271
   292    -2  -153  -181   -41   200    67   104   128    91  -154  -171
   -42  -125    67  -172  -101   -59  -130   -94  -146  -175    23   -51
   230   104    91   -16   -75  -169  -246  -203   -90    45   -99    11
    72   287   149    57   111    79   -12  -104   206     0    41    68
    78   -65  -255  -136  -115    53    52    61   -30   119  -155  -229
  -190   -36  -163  -240    98    84    85   -17     1    54    81  -173
  -205  -172  -351   -19   -86  -172   -98   -90  -169   257   126    83
   171   284   297   159    50  -150   -94   -45   -39   -12   230   201
   215   328   144 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000
 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000
 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000
 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000
 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000]

Comment: Please provide the rest of your code. Notice, that OpenCV, and specifically [`cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) can handle 16 bit images. Nevertheless, negative values won't be treated properly. So, to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), just tell us, what is the main goal of your task, what do you want to achieve in the end? Maybe, there's a better overall solution. For example, do you need to preserve the whole resolution (16 bit depth)?

Comment: I entered the rest of the code. 
My goal is to access the specific coordinates of the nrrd file and give it an RGB value.
Resolution is not taken into account in this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very precise and accurate and there can be multiple understanding of it.

First of all there is no actual 1D color to 3D color conversion, the COLOR_GRAY2BGR only convert 1-channel grey to 3-channel grey.  This conversion does not add any color, just change internal image representation so we can save it in the video  . The color can not recover. Since it is a 3D depth map, I think what you want is color mapping function like the image below.

[image]

Not sure your data is the final disparity or final depth. So you have to figur out it yourself later. But the general idea is to contain it within cv::Mat and the use opencv color mapping function to colorize.

Assume data_image_1D is np array

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
data_image_1D # this is the np array that you got it from somewhere
bw_img = np.reshape(data_image_1D,(rows,cols))
#rows and cols are the size of the depth image that you have. Try to see if you can get this convetsion working. 
im_color = cv2.applyColorMap(bw_img, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
cv2.imshow("im_color",im_color)
cv2.imshow("bw_img",bw_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But still, you have to deal with the negative disparity, minimal disparity and maximum disparity issue. That one I can leave it to you

For more 
data mapping or custom color mapping you can follow this guide https://www.learnopencv.com/applycolormap-for-pseudocoloring-in-opencv-c-python/

**edit**

I think what you want might be just a simple merge function. See this

```
import numpy as np
import nrrd
######you orginal code put it here###
bw_img = np.reshape(data_image_1D,(rows,cols))
im_color = cv2.merge([bw_img, bw_img, bw_img])
nrrd.write(filename, im_color)# Write to a NRRD file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.

But your answer is different from what I want.

I would like to change the grayscale image to RGB to colormap to the specific coordinates I want of the original image. Therefore, you should keep the grayscale even if you change RGB. RGB (128, 128, 128)

Comment: W8 exactly what you want?  you want to recover 3D location in terms of x, y, z or the colored image map?

Comment: The ultimate goal of what I want to do is to annotate the 3D image.
In this process, we use nrrd file, and when we opened nrrd file, we found that it is made of 1 channel gray scale image. So I want to work on manipulating the pixel values by converting this one channel gray scale image into a three dimensional channel.

Comment: Bro I really dont understand whats is your problem. So jsut 128 -> 128 128 128 is done by  im_color = cv2.merge([bw_img, bw_img, bw_img]) .   128 to some heat map is in the post.  If you want the 3D x,y,z, then it is https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d.  I really not sure what out put you want.  May be you can give a sample by drawing or sth.

Comment: I edited it. see if the later edit is what you want.

Comment: I am so sorry for your frustration and thank you for your reply.
My data consists of the current grayscale channel. What I'm trying to do is just change the grayscale channel to a 3-D RGB channel, not the way to do Colormap.
The array I uploaded is a slice extracted from the image. Values between 0 and 1000 are mostly gray. But I do not know how to convert these gray values to RGB. I want to change the value of all the slices I can extract to 3 channels instead of 1 channel.